# Can all manifolds be framed?

Tags: algebraic-topology

In D. Freed's [notes](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/M392C-2012/Notes/lecture2.pdf) pp.6 he defines a framing of a submanifold to be a global trivialization of the associated normal bundle (tangent space of the manifold quotient out that of the submanifold, rather than through embedding into an Euclidean space).  My question is: does a global trivialization always exist if we define normal bundle and framing this way? Why?

PS: this seems to be true (follows from tubular neighborhood theorem) if we define normal bundle using embedding into an Euclidean space, am I right?

Comment: The normal bundle is rarely trivial. Embed a manifold whose tangent bundle isn't stably trivial in some Euclidean space.

Comment: @MikeMiller: so the notes avoid this issue by assuming the manifold can be framed?

Comment: Well, if a framed manifold is a manifold equipped with a framing, then only frame-able manifolds can possibly be the underlying manifolds of framed manifolds :) (In other words, yes.)

Comment: @MikeMiller: I see. Thanks!  I thought of this might be an implicit assumption and thanks to you I am now assured.